Using `r2d2_postgres` with lazy_static doesn't work
I'm having trouble initializing a r2d2_postgres pool with lazy_static:
lazy_static! {
    static ref DB_POOL: Pool<PostgresConnectionManager<NoTls>> = {
        let manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new(config.parse().unwrap(), NoTls);
        Pool::new(manager).unwrap()
    };
}

I was using r2d2_sqlite before and everything was working fine. Here's the trace:
thread 'main' panicked at ~/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io6f17d22bba15001f/postgres-0.19.9/src/connection.rs:66:22:

Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like`block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace thread 'main' panicked at ~/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d 22bba15001f/postgres-0.19.9/src/connection.rs:66:22:

Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

stack backtrace:
   0:     0x55a3885c4dea - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::hb5961a2c6b56061b
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:116:5
   1:     0x55a3885c4dea - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h441585ce65458a75
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:     0x55a3885c4dea - std::sys::backtrace::_print_fmt::h175f8265af37e6cb
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:66:9
   3:     0x55a3885c4dea - <std::sys::backtrace::BacktraceLock::print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::haf9d4ce087fe74a0
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:39:26
   4:     0x55a3885eea53 - core::fmt::rt::Argument::fmt::h641ec953a6c58d0a
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/fmt/rt.rs:177:76
   5:     0x55a3885eea53 - core::fmt::write::h6d8d6eef4a4af1ac
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1186:21
   6:     0x55a3885c0ca3 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h9c1a7b2c301e0052
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1833:15
   7:     0x55a3885c4c32 - std::sys::backtrace::BacktraceLock::print::h5a5be8b1e95a2bbb
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:42:9
   8:     0x55a3885c6037 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::ha72f3fa07467f26a
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:268:22
   9:     0x55a3885c5e66 - std::panicking::default_hook::hcc7760cf4378effc
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:295:9
  10:     0x55a3885c6667 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hfa739d875be2cf67
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:801:13
  11:     0x55a3885c64c6 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::h9a9134f6e05b41bd
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:667:13
  12:     0x55a3885c52c9 - std::sys::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h35fa4dfdd9fe9e0c
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:170:18
  13:     0x55a3885c618c - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:665:5
  14:     0x55a3885eba20 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::hc3e7c6c5c469a97f
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/panicking.rs:74:14
  15:     0x55a387dd84c6 - tokio::runtime::context::runtime::enter_runtime::h241c00a460a1fbd3
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/context/runtime.rs:68:5
  16:     0x55a387dcbec4 - tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CurrentThread::block_on::h02f19359830f6e75
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/scheduler/current_thread/mod.rs:184:9
  17:     0x55a387dcb451 - tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on_inner::h9e97f1781ae858b6
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/runtime.rs:368:47
  18:     0x55a387dcb84e - tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on::h0d7dfbc8f7c98a37
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/runtime.rs:342:13
  19:     0x55a387dca076 - postgres::connection::Connection::poll_block_on::h5821a8625aaf933d
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/postgres-0.19.9/src/connection.rs:66:9
  20:     0x55a387de0ba6 - postgres::client::Client::close_inner::h0f9614003b00a144
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/postgres-0.19.9/src/client.rs:616:9
  21:     0x55a387de0a2e - <postgres::client::Client as core::ops::drop::Drop>::drop::he73f036533ce03e9
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/postgres-0.19.9/src/client.rs:20:17
  22:     0x55a387dc95f7 - core::ptr::drop_in_place<postgres::client::Client>::hcd1026e4c7ab4e6e
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:574:1
  23:     0x55a3877360f7 - core::ptr::drop_in_place<r2d2::Conn<postgres::client::Client>>::h7a97120ab11c206a
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:574:1
  24:     0x55a3877d9d6a - r2d2::Pool<M>::try_get_inner::h2e39ae956ee0a512
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/r2d2-0.8.10/src/lib.rs:483:13
  25:     0x55a3877d929e - r2d2::Pool<M>::get_timeout::hceeb88dd5f4d411f
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/r2d2-0.8.10/src/lib.rs:424:19
  26:     0x55a3877da091 - r2d2::Pool<M>::get::hea1b50a653f8c20b
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/r2d2-0.8.10/src/lib.rs:411:9
  27:     0x55a3875f1348 - joogle::db::sites::init_table::h717a8c0acd2e64eb
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/Documents/Projects/joogle/src/db/sites.rs:9:20
  28:     0x55a3877a51c1 - joogle::main::{{closure}}::h57b83d07a13c3021
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/Documents/Projects/joogle/src/main.rs:84:5
  29:     0x55a3877d36cd - <core::pin::Pin<P> as core::future::future::Future>::poll::h175dfb280ef2cdf7
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/future/future.rs:123:9
  30:     0x55a3877893df - tokio::runtime::park::CachedParkThread::block_on::{{closure}}::h66545313ddef3df1
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/park.rs:281:63
  31:     0x55a387786326 - tokio::runtime::coop::with_budget::h6efd943802836fc8
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/coop.rs:107:5
  32:     0x55a387786326 - tokio::runtime::coop::budget::hf96bceea67332ee3
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/coop.rs:73:5
  33:     0x55a387786326 - tokio::runtime::park::CachedParkThread::block_on::ha202f72947e1d848
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/park.rs:281:31
  34:     0x55a387800720 - tokio::runtime::context::blocking::BlockingRegionGuard::block_on::h0613e378a4cd988e
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/context/blocking.rs:66:9
  35:     0x55a38765032e - tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::MultiThread::block_on::{{closure}}::h04a9fc77b29210c2
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/mod.rs:87:13
  36:     0x55a3876956e0 - tokio::runtime::context::runtime::enter_runtime::h6d4263a341803676
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/context/runtime.rs:65:16
  37:     0x55a38764fea1 - tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::MultiThread::block_on::h03c08d760b2dd6cb
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/scheduler/multi_thread/mod.rs:86:9
  38:     0x55a38766fe12 - tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on_inner::h05d2c20946a5ced0
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/runtime.rs:370:45
  39:     0x55a38767144d - tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on::h0dfd39080eed2e28
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.42.0/src/runtime/runtime.rs:340:13
  40:     0x55a387759b40 - rocket::async_run::h6e04995ce127c884
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rocket-0.5.1/src/lib.rs:250:18
  41:     0x55a3877598c9 - rocket::async_main::h5d0f258c8f30266d
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rocket-0.5.1/src/lib.rs:282:5
  42:     0x55a38766eb32 - joogle::main::h8ef69abf974f528d
                               at /home/johanmontorfano/Documents/Projects/joogle/src/main.rs:80:23
  43:     0x55a3877299ab - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h4e8011241f5ad359
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
  44:     0x55a3877d296e - std::sys::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h4e59c8bf79320b4b
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/sys/backtrace.rs:154:18
  45:     0x55a387690e41 - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h0666c996fa6c7454
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/rt.rs:164:18
  46:     0x55a3885b9f40 - core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once::h5b8616fa64754f67
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:284:13
  47:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hb9ece8d760e9492d
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:557:40
  48:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::panicking::try::hec186f0da2e0e0f2
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:520:19
  49:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h21bd59bf1b1faa4d
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panic.rs:348:14
  50:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}::hc035020e9c22a2ad
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/rt.rs:143:48
  51:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::panicking::try::do_call::ha826433f6400f059
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:557:40
  52:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::panicking::try::h6ba5225898f870bf
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panicking.rs:520:19
  53:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::panic::catch_unwind::hb2c7060d484d84a5
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/panic.rs:348:14
  54:     0x55a3885b9f40 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::hc44f35ca2c603ce0
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/rt.rs:143:20
  55:     0x55a387690e1a - std::rt::lang_start::h3749fb1487ab32bd
                               at /rustc/7042c269c166191cd5d8daf0409890903df7af57/library/std/src/rt.rs:163:17
  56:     0x55a38766eb5e - main
  57:     0x7fb608729248 - __libc_start_call_main
  58:     0x7fb60872930b - __libc_start_main_impl
  59:     0x55a3875ef3b5 - _start
  60:                0x0 - <unknown>
thread 'main' panicked at core/src/panicking.rs:229:5:
panic in a destructor during cleanup
thread caused non-unwinding panic. aborting.
[1]    12383 IOT instruction (core dumped)  cargo run


I tried using OneCell and other techniques I found on the web, but nothing solves this issue.
